# Fancybox, Jquery Validate & position:absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fancybox, css-position

I have a fancybox http://fancybox.net which contains a form.

On the form I am running the jQuery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator

Error messages are positioned directly under the inputs using position:absolute and a top margin.

```
var validator = $("#contact-us").validate({
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",
            phone: "Please enter your phone number",
            email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address"
        }
    });

// Launch lightbox

$(".launch-form").fancybox({
    'speedIn'           :   500,
    'speedOut'          :   300,
    'overlayOpacity'    :   0.9,
    'overlayColor'      :   '#000',
    onComplete          :   function() {$('#cta-name').focus();},
    onCleanup           :   function() {validator.resetForm();}

});

label.error {
    background-color: #ae4136;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21px;
    line-height:1.2;
    height:12px;
}
```

It's all working great, except for when I generate the error messages the second time I launch the popup (ie: after having reset the form).  The messages show 30px lower:

[image: The first time I launch the fancybox]
[image: The second time I launch the fancybox (ie: after having cleared the plugin]

Any ideas as to Why the position is being recalculated?  I am using FF14, but the same issue appears on chrome.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your HTML markup but `absolute` positioning is with respect its nearest parent element that has `position: <anything other than static, eg. relative or absolute>` applied to it.

You could do two things:

1. **Don't** use positioning and just use `block` elements and `margin`
2. Wrap each label and field in its **own** containing element, like a `div` or a `fieldset`

Comment: Thanks Moin.  I've done some more digging, it seems its related to the element defaulting to display:inline - simple fix - change to display:block and remove margin.